# How to transform select options from views exposed filters to clickable link areas?

Tags: 8, theming, views

I have asked more generally in stack overflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491094/how-to-transform-select-options-to-clickables-link-areas?noredirect=1#comment85985442_49491094

How can I make my exposed filters look like this?[image]

```
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-field-video-theme-target-id" id="edit-field-video-theme-target-id" name="field_video_theme_target_id" class="form-select"><option value="All" selected="selected">- Tout -</option><option value="9">A*midex</option><option value="11">Bibliothèque</option><option value="10">Relation entreprise</option><option value="8">Université</option></select>
```

Is it possible to transform select/options to ul/li?

Is it possible to override the template `views-exposed-form--videos.html.twig`?

Comment: Have you tried [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)? If I remember correctly, it has a feature to turn options into clickable links

Comment: i am not that keen anymore to use alpha versions

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to override the template, you shall just create it in your theme and then clear the cache.

In your new template you can just change the select list to a ul

The template that you want to override may only contain `{{ form }}`.
Then you must find the preprocess function in the module or theme.

Comment: it does not seem as simple since the template for views exposed form  is {{ form }} . How can i go deep inside?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing integrated into drupal at the moment but you can probably use [select2Buttons](https://github.com/o-sam-o/jquery.select2Buttons) in your theme.

just include it in your theme and in custom javascript you can call

```
$('select[name=simple-select]').select2Buttons();
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly you could create a file `views-exposed-form--videos.html.twig`(I am not sure with the name just check it with twig debug) and add the following code in it

```
<# add your styled html with attribute name = "field_video_theme_target_id" #>

<ul name="field_video_theme_target_id" class="form-select">
  <li value="All" selected="selected">- Tout -</li>
  <li value="9">A*midex</li>
  <li value="11">Bibliothèque</li>
  <li value="10">Relation entreprise</li>
  <li value="8">Université</li>
</ul>
{{ form|without('field_video_theme_target_id') }}
```

Comment: it would be good to keep the logic. options are taxonomies from a entity reference field

Comment: kint() or dump() the variable field_video_theme_target_id in the twig file. i think you will be able to display the values there using some loop.